# How to assign table ownership to multiple users or group in Redshift

Tags: security, amazon-redshift, sql-grant, aws-redshift

I was wondering if there is a way how to assign table owner to a group or to multiple users in Redshift? If not, is there any workaround you use to solve this need?

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My understanding is that there is no way to achieve this seemingly desirable state.  It seems to be [how Redshift is designed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Privileges.html).

The only work-around I am aware of is to either have the 'owner' of the object' execute any commands that required 'owner' privilege, or to have the owner run a command to transfer (note not 'confer' sadly) the ownership of the object to the target user that wishes to make modifications.

```
alter table test.test_table owner to test_user;
```

After executing the above, test_user will be the owner of test.test_table, and would be able to perform 'owner-only' commands such as alter/drop/vacuum etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found out the same thing.